# AWS Route 53 ( change CNAME to A record type and assign IP address in 400 subdomains )

Tags: amazon-route53

I have 400 subdomain mapped to single CNAME record, now i want to change all these record TYPE to A record and assign IP address, how can i do that in one go.

Reagrds
Jyotir

Comment: Well i was able to achieve the task via python boto utility. You need to install python boto package on your linux box and use IAM to get full access to route53. Next you need to create a hidden .boto file in home directory with access and secret key for the user you have granted route53 access via IAM